# Android EditText in RelativeLayout expanding too fast

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multi-line `EditText` in my Android application which resides in a `RelativeLayout`, which is itself a child of a `GridLayout` with 2 columns. Each `RelativeLayout` has a columnWeight of 1, which results in 2 `EditText` each taking up half the screen. The width of each layout is set to 0dp in order for the weights to take precedence.

The height of each `RelativeLayout` is set to `wrap_content`, as is the height of the EditTexts themselves. I would expect the height of the `RelativeLayout` to expand linearly with the `EditText`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Instead, the layout expands the height of one line for roughly every other character, such that an 8 letter word causes the height of the `RelativeLayout` to almost quadruple in size. My gut is telling me that it has something to do with the weighting/width, but I can't find anything online to confirm that. Why is this happening?

```
<GridLayout
     android:id="@+id/proficiencyGrid"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/featuresWrapper"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:columnCount="2"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:rowCount="6" >
```

....

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/personalityWrapper"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_column="0"
     android:layout_columnWeight="1"
     android:layout_gravity="fill"
     android:layout_row="4" >
```

....

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/personalityDialog"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/personalitySeparator"
     android:inputType="textMultiLine"
     android:padding="15dp"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white"
     android:textSize="16sp" >
```

[image: Height Expand EditText Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my layout issue by using horizontal LinearLayouts rather than trying to put them all in a GridLayout. It doesn't answer the question of why my RelativeLayouts were expanding at the rate they were, but it does provide an alternative. As weighting is a relatively new thing for GridLayouts, I am still convinced that it has to do with the width of the layout being 0dp to allow for weighting to occur, but no one has confirmed this.